# Is there a way to define the Color with Opacity in the constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is an example constructor and I want to define the **Color** with **Opacity** like this;

```
      SelectListBuilder({
        this.activeColor = const Color(0xFFBFFFD5).withOpacity(.6)
      });

The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type 'Color'.dart(invalid_cast_new_expr)
```

Comment: `const Color(0x99BFFFD5)`

Comment: I want to use it with opacity.

Comment: it has opacity - `0.6`

Comment: Yes but I have got an error; The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type 'Color'.dart(invalid_cast_new_expr)

Comment: they use `const Color(...)` everywhere without any errors: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c969b8af7b48bd0f4e3329ed3f112f41136d8bcd/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart#L51

Comment: Can you post the code of SelectListBuilde?

Comment: Thanks to everybody, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
= const Color.fromRGBO(0xBF, 0xFF, 0xD5, .6);
```